# Two jQuery codes but only one executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions in jQuery. One of them looks for image extensions from form and another is getting image dimensions and triggers an `alert()` when an image is not big enough.

Both functions are correctly executed in demos but together only one is executed. Only part where extensions is getting is executed. Sorry for the length of the code but it was the only way to show the problem.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.checkFileType = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            allowedExtensions: [],
            success: function () {},
            error: function () {}
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).on('change', function () {
                var value = $(this).val(),
                    file = value.toLowerCase(),
                    extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
                    options.error();
                    $(this).focus();
                } else {
                    options.success();
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#filput").on('change', function () {
    var fr = new FileReader;

    fr.onload = function () { // file is loaded
        var img = new Image;

        img.onload = function () {
            // image is loaded; sizes are available 
            var w = img.width
            if (w < 500) {
                alert("too small");
            } else {
                alert("big enough");
            }
        };
        img.src = fr.result;
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$(function () {
    $('#filput').checkFileType({
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You've put an extra symbol on `success: function() {},`

Comment: yes there is no it in code. its becouse of coping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only part where extentions is getting is executed

That code is wrapped by `$(function() { ... });` so, you should probably put both pieces of code there:

```
$(function() {
    $("#filput").on('change', function () {
        var fr = new FileReader;
        // ...
    });

    $('#filput').checkFileType({
        // ...
    });
});
```

Based on what you have described, the input element wasn't present yet at the time your code is run; by putting both code segments in the DOMReady event handler, you're making sure it exists.